# Javascript data not in correct cell

Tags: javascript, arm, webserver, microcontroller, stm32

I am implementing a server on an STM32F4 MCU and am having issues with the javascript. The controller responds to the the character "s" with the following

"text/javascript\n\nvar CH1= 789"

The browser is not putting the value (789) in the correct cell as shown in the image below, its outside the table

[image]

The server is sending all the required data but the browser is not building it correctly. Any ideas why this may be?

Thanks.

**HTML code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
         <head> 
                   <script src=/s></script>
                   <title>Test HTM</title> 

         </head>
         <body> 
         <table> 
         <tbody>
         <tr> 
         <td valign="top"><table border="0" style="font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;"> 
         <tbody><tr><th colspan="3">Controller                                           
         </th></tr><tr>
         <td>
         <table> 
         <tbody><tr><td valign="below"><table border="1" style="font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;">
         <tbody><tr><th colspan=\"2\">ADC</th></tr> 
                 <tr><td>Ch1</td><script>document.write(CH1)</script></tr> 
                 <tr><td>Ch2</td><td>0000</td></tr> 
                 <tr><td>Ch3</td><td>0000</td></tr> 

         </tbody>
         </table> 
         </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: Hey there. Please have a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Folks are generally happy to help out but the amount of code you've posted represents quite a substantial time investment.

Comment: I reduced the html code to its most basic and removed the non-referenced tables.

Comment: You should format your HTML and see if you are missing any closing tags. For the future I would  suggest avoiding nested tables as it leads to a very complex structure.

Comment: @ Andrew Lohr - You are right, i reduced the complexity and its ok now. I was worried it was something to do with the server end. Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because document.write won't write what you want at the location that the call is.

Personally, I would set an id on the cell I want to fill, like `<td id="cell1"></td>` and then use

```
document.getElementById('cell1').innerHTML = CH1
```